# C#, Web performance test creation error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing, web-testing

I am working on a project that needs something load/performance tested.
I need to upload a file like it would come from the browser.
I know how that works so I create a Web and Load testproject in my solution.
Then I create a Webtest (or a load test). It starts loading for a while and then my visual studio (2017) throws this error:

[image: Screenshot of error from VS]

The text in the error states:

`Test settings with id {someguid} were not found.`

It creates an `Local.testsettings` file like usual and an `Webtest1.webtest`. This error also pops up after you clicked "OK" and want to create another web or loadtest.

This prevents me from adding static files to the test (that have to be uploaded).

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be precise about the steps you are doing, at what stage the error occurs and what files have been created at that time. Also state whether other tests have been created OK with the computer and the Visual Studio version that gets the failure. Web tests and load tests are different, be clear about which is being created when the fault occurs. My first suggestion is that you run the Visual Studio installer and do a repair.

Comment: Did you already full-text search for that GUID in the whole solution? there is usually an abandoned Link to a webtest with this ID that has probably changed!